# How to add an edge highlight to a CSS shape?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to create a highlight on a CSS shape as shown below.
[image]

There will also be content inside of the hexagon including image and text,
The highlight I am referring to is the part in the top left.

the code I currently have for creating the hexagon is:

HTML

```
<div class="hexagon-big"></div>
```

CSS

```
.hexagon-big {
    position: relative;
    
    width: 200px; 
    height: 115.47px;
    background-color: #343434;
   
    
    
}

.hexagon-big:before,
.hexagon-big:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon-big:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border-bottom: 57.74px solid #343434;   
}

.hexagon-big:after {
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 57.74px solid #343434;
}
```

There is other code for the content but i left it out because I don't think it is necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in this answer is heavily based on the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67516873/7638119). To use [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) and stacked gradients is by far the smartest thing to do here, but I still wanted to post this in order to show, how this solution could be improved and adjusted for your use case (text box, coloring, variables for maintenance, etc.).

```css
.hexagon-big {
  /* define box and text space */
  width: 200px;
  height: 230px;
  padding: 10.8% 5px; /* adjust text box padding here; mind that top/bottom tip are part of the box */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* width/height should include padding */
  /* text formatting (optional) */
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  /* hex shape */
  --hex-col: hsl(0deg 0% 20%); /* just your #343434 as a HSL color */
  --hex-shadow: hsl(0deg 0% 50%); /* increased lightness by 15% to define highlight root color; 100% would be fully white */
  background:
    conic-gradient(at top, var(--hex-col) 232deg, transparent 0), /* change the angle of the shadow at "232deg": increase → narrower, decrease → wider */
    linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--hex-shadow), var(--hex-col) 55%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 25%,0% 75%,50% 100%,100% 75%,100% 25%,50% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon-big">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</div>
```

It should also be mentioned that your current way of using `border` is well better supported by older browsers than [`clip-path`](https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path) and [`conic-gradient`](https://caniuse.com/?search=conic-gradient) (same with [`var()`](https://caniuse.com/css-variables)).
If this should be a problem, you might have to add another HTML tag and work out a way with `transform: matrix(...)` and `box-shadow: inset ...` (for example).

Answer (score 4):

Do the hexagon shape differently and you can rely on gradient to create that highlight effect:

```css
.hex {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin:0 5px;
  background:
    conic-gradient(at top,#000 230deg, #0000 0),
    linear-gradient(to bottom left,#fff , #000 60%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 25%,0% 75%,50% 100%,100% 75%,100% 25%,50% 0%);
}

.hex::before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 115%; /* 100%/cos(30)  */
}
```

```html
<div class="hex"></div>
```